# How to display calender on cloned form using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an date input area using Bootstrap-dateinput

```
<div class="form-group row">
   <div class="col-xs-8">
      <label class="control-label">Date</label>
      <div class="input-group date" id="dp3" data-date="12-02-2014" data-date-format="mm-dd-yyyy">
         <input class="form-control" type="text" required="" placeholder="Date"  name="date[]" value="">
         <span class="input-group-addon">
         <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
         </span>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Jquery Script To clone this form:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $( document ).on( 'click', '.btn-add', function ( event ) {
            event.preventDefault();

            var field = $(this).closest( '.form-group' );
            var field_new = field.clone();

            $(this)
                .toggleClass( 'btn-default' )
                .toggleClass( 'btn-add' )
                .toggleClass( 'btn-danger' )
                .toggleClass( 'btn-remove' )
                .html( '-' );

            field_new.find( 'input' ).val( '' );
            field_new.insertAfter( field );
        } );

    </script>
```

And Script to display calender:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.input-group .date').datepicker({
...
    });
</script>
```

But when New input area is created it do not show calender when clicked

I tried adding onclick

```
$(".input-group .date").click(function(){
$('.input-group .date').datepicker({
...
});
```

But yet seems there is some problem Can you please tell whats wrong and how to fix it ?

Comment: If you clone `form-group`, you have two elements with the id `dp3`. That will not work.

Comment: Can you please suggest an fix ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This:

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" required="" placeholder="Date"  name="date[]" value="" onclick="$(this).datepicker({
...
});">
```